# How to use Google Analytics in Alloy Titanium Appcelerator

Tags: google-analytics, titanium, titanium-alloy, titanium-modules, titanium-android

I have downloaded the zip file from https://github.com/Sitata/titanium-google-analytics After extacting which I got folder named - titanium-google-analytics-master

But there is no documentation for a newbie like me to use it in my Alloy Mobile Project. like which file should be placed where and what to write to include them etc.

Can some one please help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You must have missed it. It is located as `ReadMe.md` in the same github repo. Have a look at [the manual](https://github.com/Sitata/titanium-google-analytics/blob/master/README.md). It teaches you everything about the setup and the usage.

Comment: I have already gone through that whole page but it is not written that after downloading the zip file which folder to be placed where and how to include that plugin into App. It only starts from creating a variable **var GA = require("analytics.google");** But if I do not know which folder to put where, and which file to include in which file of my alloy and by which method, then how come I can use it? I come from PHP and HTML background and know how to include Javascript files in my HTML/PHP page, but how can I do it in Titanium Alloy App?

Comment: And without pasting folder into any relevant APP folder, and include how can I start from line require("analytics.google");

Comment: Oh ok. I wasn't aware that you had a question regarding the basic Titanium module setup. Here you go: http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Using_a_Module It perfectly describes how to manage the zip file and everything which follows.

Comment: Have you successfully imported your module into your project?

Comment: Hi Robin, Thanks for your help. The problem is now resolved by downloading another Google Analytics Module. This module was buggy.

Comment: Cool that you found a solution for your problem. Maybe you can comment your new module to make it easier for others with the same problem?

Comment: I have been searching for any google analytics model that will work under titanium sdk 8.2.0 but is it me or are many modules abandoned and defunct ? I can't get any to work, all modules break the building with compilation errors.

tried:
analytics.google, ti.ga (including a couple of branches), titanium-google-analytics